# AngularJS menu layout desktop and mobile responsive

Tags: html, css, angularjs, mobile, responsive-design

I have website with AngularJS with this menu

[image: Website]

but this is what happen when it loaded in mobile

[image: mobile]

Can I achieve layout like this in mobile?

[image: mobile expected]

this is html Code

```
    <div flex="nogrow">
        <div layout="row" layout-align="end center">
            <div class="dashboard-button-right pointer" ng-repeat="btn in dashboardButtons" ng-click="dashboardClick(btn, $event)" 
                 ng-class="{'{{btn.active_class}}': btn.active === true, '{{btn.class}}': btn.active === false}">
              {{btn.label}}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Thanks before

Comment: yeah sure you can achieve but you need to write responsive media queries

Answer (score 0):

You can use **media queries** and also mention **bootstrap xs columns**. If you are making it responsive on **xtra small screen**, you need to use bootstrap column for **alignment** then you can use **css media queries** to style them. In fact for a **responsive website**, you need to define its **behavior** and **align** it on all 4 screens (lg,md,sm,xs).

I'm assuming you know bootstrap *grid system* already. I hope it solved your question and if you need to ask something let me know.